# How would I test payment methods within magento 1.8.0.0.?

Tags: magento, admin, magento-1.8

I was just wondering if anybody knows how to test magento's payment options.

I have got a few questions.

1. Do I need to change any code within any of the pages?
2. Do I need to make any changes to the admin settings ?
3. Is there a simple setting to test these payment methods out?
4. Is there only certain payment methods that you can actually check?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No you dont need to change any code. Its all handled from backend.

Generally for development purpose we use Cash on delivery or Check/Money Order payment method.
So you just need to enable these method from backend.

For Testing Credit Cards enable 'Saved CC' Payment Method and during checkout use test credit card type `VISA`, card number `4111111111111111` with any date of future for Expiration Date and any cvv number

Additionally for proper payment gateway integration You will need to purchase payment gateway which will provide Magento Module along with it. This Payment Method will have 2 modes test and live that are configurable from banckend. So with test mode you can continue development and testing.

Similarly with Paypal. Yo can setup Sandbox test account. Module is already there.

Comment: I have same problem too dude. Do I have to activate Sandbox test account with Credit Card and Confirm Email too ? And can I test it on localhost ? Thank

Comment: is there no way you can test this without having to download an extension all i want to do is just test the credit cards or debit cards thats all i need to test because the site will only use these payment methods

Comment: @PrabhatSubedi Sandbox will be developer account so you wont need to confirm credit card to active, only email will do.

Comment: @user3021997 Yes you can use Test Credit Payment as well. I have updated answer

Comment: @DeependraSingh just wondering how will i know if it has been done as a test because of me never doing this before i dont want to test it and then find out that i am moving around real money for the company that im doing this for, is there no guide or is there a way you could show me what settings are needed for me to change to make sure i don't cause any problems with the database that i am using for this version of magento site

Comment: Note that you may have a theme or module that will validate the CC fields and tell you that it is not a valid CC. You may need to manually disable these.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Express Checkout:

1. Go to [developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com) and log in using your PayPal account (it doesn't matter if the acount is empty or not).
2. Click on the menu item on the top dashboard and then select **Accounts** from the sidebar.
3. There, you will find 2 test accounts already set for you. You can modify the existing acounts or create new ones.

[This post may help you.](https://ionicmelon.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/paypal-sandbox-accounts-for-testing-magento-payments/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can test on local host with setup sendbox account.

Answer (score 0):

You can **create a 99% discount coupon**.

*PS: From my experience, that's the standard to test live websites. The sandbox payment only works on staging/dev sites, as it puts the entire website on dev mode.*